# Is there a pictorial introduction to homology of surfaces? Are they easy to visualize like the fundamental group?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, surfaces

I have come across the concept of homology groups of surfaces (so I am seeing $H_1(M, \mathbb{Z})$ and $H_1(M - X, \mathbb{Z})$ and $H_1(M, X, \mathbb{Z})$, where $M$ is a surface, and $X \subset M$ is a finite set of points, for example, section 4.5 [here](https://www.college-de-france.fr/media/jean-christophe-yoccoz/UPL15305_PisaLecturesJCY2007.pdf)). I have not studied any algebraic topology yet, and just started reading Hatcher.

The surfaces I am dealing with are quite concrete. For example, torrii with a number of removed points. What do those groups look like? Are they easy to visualize like the fundamental group?

Comment: $H_1$ is the abelianization of $\pi_1$. You can read about that in Hatcher as well.

Comment: I think this answers your question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185903/